# Active AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mootools, prototypejs

Prototype stores the number of active AJAX requests in `Ajax.activeRequestCount`. Is there something similar in jQuery/Mootools etc or something that can be used from XMLHttpRequest?. Ideally I need a library independent method of detecting the number of active AJAX requests within a page. If not, a method for each library would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype only keeps track of the number of active requests made using Prototype APIs. If you were to make an AJAX request using any other method, `Ajax.activeRequestCount` will not be affected. There is no cross-library way to keep track of every request made, unless you were to keep track of them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`$.active` for jQuery, as I see from the documentation

MooTools doesn't seem to have one ([here's the Request class source](http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Request/Request.js))

Perhaps for MooTools you could make an intermediary function to call Ajax, and make your own count there?

Answer (score 1):

Mootools request objects are initiallized once and resused, you can keep count when initializing.

BTW, I bet that the reson you want to keep this counted is not a requirement with mootools, due to its single instance structure, look into it!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has an (undocumented?) ajax active counter: jQuery.active

Roger Hu has a [blog post](http://hustoknow.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-jqueryactive-code-works.html) about it.